# Rails database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema, models

Caveat: I'm new to rails and app development in general so please excuse any noobness.

I'm trying to figure out the database schema for my app. I've got the following models: Company, User(employee), Product, Client and Order.
Background: The company has a database which is maintained by users(employees). The client can visit the company site, login and then access the database to see the products and their stock levels. From this they can then make a purchase i.e. an order. I've got the following schema with these associations:

- Company: has_many users, has_many products, has_many clients, has_many orders through clients.
- User(employee): belongs_to Company
- Product: belongs_to Company
- Client: belongs_to Company
- Order: belongs_to Company through clients

Is this correct or am I missing something? 
Would be grateful for any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it is way to broad and the information you supplied is not sufficient to tell anything - what is the difference between user and a client?, why do orders belong to the company? In general association looks all right to me, but I had absolutely no idea what is your requirements.

Comment: @BroiSatse Sorry... Users work for the company and update things like the product information, stock levels etc. Clients purchase products. I just assumed that orders would have to be connected to the company as they are selling the product.

Comment: Do clients have to login in order to do the purchase?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes they do. It isn't a common ecommerce site. It will be a specialized site for my company which sells industrial bearings to a select few clients. Basically they can access our database to view what products we have in stock and make an order.

Comment: Do other companies can sell stuff as well? I think this should be turned into a proper meeting of some kind to produce the high level design - there is way too many unknowns here.

Comment: @BroiSatse there's only one company - sorry for any ambiguity! I've updated the original question to clear things up a bit. How would you like to meet?

Comment: Oh, I was just suggesting that that's what should happen between you and your architect. If there is only one Company, you don't really need such a model, do you?

Comment: @BroiSatse I see. I assumed having a company model would allow for the others to belong_to one main model making associations easier. Maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are indeed missing some tables.

Do you need categories ? You need a categories table.

can you order have many products ? you need another table (1 order has many order details ).

How are you going to store product details ? you need a table there as well if you have multiple size for each products for example.

I also don't really understand why do you need a client model vs using your user model for clients ?

`Company`
`has many :clients,class_name:"User"`

Comment: In answer to your questions: I'm not sure about categories, can you elaborate? A client can make an order containing many products but I already have both Order and Product models, why do I need another? The Product model stores the product data. Users are employees who update the database and Clients are customers.

Comment: How are you going to store you products inside your order ? You can't.

Usually you need to have one order table and one order_details table with each product. 
If you don't how are you going to save multiple products into 1 line of the database.. ? 
`Order_details ,  order_id_1, size A , color B`
`Order_details, order_id_1 , size C , color Z`

So for this example the same order " 1 " got 2 product stored in the product details. How do you hope to do this with only one table ? 
They are probably ways. but ugly ways.

Comment: As for Users/Employees , each can have their own roles but still be a single User table.

For example on my project User is also , Customer , designer and admin. I don't need 3 tables for that. Just set the foreign key to be employee_id instead of user_id and do your association properly.

Have 2 table isn't wrong, i just think it's not necessary.

As for category this was just my 2 cent having done an ecommerce website before.

Comment: You should use a schema design it would help you see things better.

http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/ for example

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, it seems like a good start.

Only flaw :

```
class Client
  has_many :orders
end
```

is missing.

Still, I would make it obvious that "Users" are really Employees and "Clients", Customers. (Hope I'm not crossing any line here)